# Abstract Factory Pattern: Typescript TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, typescript

//This is my animal interface

//IAnimal.ts

```
export interface IAnimal{
    getAnimal():string;
}
```

//concrete classes
//Lion.ts

```
import { IAnimal } from "./IAnimal";

export class Lion implements IAnimal{
   public getAnimal(): string {
       return "Lion";
    }
    
}
```

//Shark.ts

```
import { IAnimal } from "./IAnimal";

export class Shark implements IAnimal {
    getAnimal(): string {
      return "Shark";
    }

}
```

// Abstract factory (super factory)

//AnimalAbstractFactory.ts

```
import { IAnimal } from "./IAnimal";
import { LandAnimalFactory } from "./LandAnimalFactory";
import { SeaAnimalFactory } from "./SeaAnimalFactory";

export default abstract class AnimalAbstractFactory{
 public abstract getAnimalType(animalname:string):IAnimal | null;
 public static createAnimalFactory(factoryType:string):AnimalAbstractFactory | null{
    if(factoryType == 'Land'){
        return new LandAnimalFactory();
    }else if( factoryType == 'Sea'){
        return new SeaAnimalFactory();
    }else{
        return null;
    }
 }
}
```

// sub factories

//LandAnimalFactory.ts

```
import animals   from "./AnimalAbstractFactory";
import { IAnimal } from "./IAnimal";
import { Lion } from "./Lion";
import { Tiger } from "./Tiger";


export class LandAnimalFactory extends animals {
    public getAnimalType(animalname: string): IAnimal | null {
        if (animalname == 'Lion') {
            return new Lion();
        }
        else if (animalname == 'Tiger') {
            return new Tiger();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

// SeaAnimalFactory.ts

```
import animals  from "./AnimalAbstractFactory";
import { IAnimal } from "./IAnimal";
import { Octopus } from "./Octobus";
import { Shark } from "./Shark";


export class SeaAnimalFactory extends animals {
    public getAnimalType(animalname: string): IAnimal | null {
        if (animalname == 'shark') {
            return new Shark();
        } else if (animalname == "Octopus") {
            return new Octopus();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

// Main driver code

```
import animals from './AnimalAbstractFactory'

let animalFactory = animals.createAnimalFactory('Land');
let animal = animalFactory?.getAnimalType('Lion');

if(animal){
    console.log(animal.getAnimal());
}
```

When i run npx ts-node getting error

**The code throws error

class LandAnimalFactory extends Abstract_AnimialFactory_1.AnimalFactory {
^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null**

Comment: Hi there! I copy and pasted your code into the typescript playground and got no error. It outputs `"Lion"`. https://tsplay.dev/NV3Pxm Can you [edit] your question to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the error?

Comment: The error imples you have a typo `Abstract_AnimialFactory_1` looks mistyped. I think this name is autogenerated so good to check if you included the right filename etc

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).